# Django Simple Captcha: Table not found

Tags: django, django-forms, captcha

On my local development machine I've already successfully installed django-simple-captcha. However, when I run it on the production server, the table is not found, resulting in a `TemplateSyntaxError`.

> Caught DatabaseError while rendering: no such table: captcha_captchastore

I'm using sqlite3 as database engine and had already run `python manage.py syncdb` and checked the created tables with the following SQL statement:

> sqlite> select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table';
>   auth_permission
>   auth_group_permissions
>   auth_group
>   auth_user_user_permissions
>   auth_user_groups
>   auth_user
>   auth_message
>   django_content_type
>   django_session
>   django_site
>   django_admin_log
>   captcha_captchastore

However, even if all the other tables work just fine, `captcha_captchastore` is not found. What could be possible reasons for this failure and how to fix it?

---

Additional findings:
When I run the Django development server on the production machine and check back everything works fine. Apparently it has something to do with the way I run Django. I currently have a setup with nginx and Django via fastcgi. The launch command is the following:

```
python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8081 --settings=settings
```

How can this influence finding the database or not? Probably there is a path problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't find out how the path to databases is constructed when you are in a template environment or in the scope of another app, but setting an absolute path name fixes the issue.